# What are the locations of all double battles in Pokemon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm looking for all the double battles that exist in Pokemon X. Where are they?

Comment: Why would you want such a thing ?

Comment: It just seems like a long to collect and not very useful information.

Comment: I'm on mobile otherwise I'd do it, but it should be possible to look through the [Pokemon Trainer Types for XY](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trainer), find which ones have double battles (like the 'Mysterious Sisters'), and from there look at the individual encounters. A little arduous but definitely finite and do-able.

Answer (score 1):

Without listing all the double battles in the game, if you need a way to teach a Smeargle moves or if you need general XP, there's always the restaurants that will offer you repeatable pokemon battles (some of which are double, triple and rotation battles).

More information [over here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lumiose_City_restaurants).